# Why ActiveSupport try() is override when I define a method try with a bang

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, enums, activesupport

What a surprise when I defined a method the set my ActiveRecord User attribute `currency_code` to Turkish lira (TRY).

So in `User` I defined:

`define_method("try!"){ update! currency_code: :try }`.

And it apparently defined both `try()` and `try!()` with the same block
and the result for `User.first.try` is updating my user instance.

I investigate but I don't understand where the `try()` (Active support that prevent you call to a method to raise if it's nil) is override and now execute an update.

To be sure I defined the same one for USD

`define_method("usd!"){ update! currency_code: :usd }` and this one is working the right way. No `usd()` method defined here.

I'm not looking for a fix but an explication to this magic :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because ActiveSupport's [`try`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activesupport/ActiveSupport%2FTryable:try) method also uses `try!` internally, at least in Rails 5.1:

```
# File 'lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb', line 5

def try(*a, &b)
  try!(*a, &b) if a.empty? || respond_to?(a.first)
end
```

Comment: I missed this one! Thanks!

Comment: I used ActiveRecord `enum` to define my currencies, so do you agree that the protection line 193 https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/21e5fd4a2a1c162ad33708d3e01b1fda165f204d/activerecord/lib/active_record/enum.rb#L193 should prevent me to define `try!`